# Do I need a master's degree to land a job in AI?

Tags: masters

I'm an undergraduate student pursuing B.Tech IT from India. I'm entering my final year. While going through requirements for a job in the AI field online, I could see most of the big competitors ask for either a Master's degree or experience of 2 to 5 years in the AI field.

I thought having a mediocre self-taught knowledge in deep learning gained through decent academic projects can land me in an entry-level job/intern from which I could develop my career. But after seeing the above trend from job recruiters, I have a heavy doubt.

Please help me to decide whether I should try to enter the field with some luck by grabbing any slightest opportunity I get (I doubt whether I'll get that) or should pursue a master's degree from a good college? (I'm financially constrained too to do a Master's degree abroad).

Answer (score 1):

## If you want to work on AI in academia, probably yes.

I can't speak about what industry wants, but if you want to work on it in an academic setting, then you will almost definitely need a PhD degree, because basically every job doing academic research needs a PhD. Depending on how your university manages its PhD program, you might need a Master's Degree to apply, or it might include the Master's Degree as a coursework component of the PhD program.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but this depends on the job ad you want to answer.

I think you gave the most important answer yourself:

> I could see most of the big competitors ask for either a Master's degree **or experience of 2 to 5 years in the AI field**.

Getting a master degree will probably at least take two years, so you may also try to gain experience in other ways and possibly make more money in this time.

Of course the type of knowledge will be a bit different (probably more applied) and the type of jobs may be different as well, on the other hand many jobs will probably be the same and not require that much of the masters degree, if you don't mind being more focused on the AI and less generalistic.